# perl style regex to match nth item in a list

Tags: regex

Trying to match the third item in this list:

```
/text word1, word2, some_other_word, word_4
```

I tried using this perl style regex to no avail:

```
([^, ]*, ){$m}([^, ]*),
```

I want to match ONLY the third word, nothing before or after, and no commas or whitespace. I need it to be a regex, this is not in a program but UltraEdit for a word file.

What can I use to match some_other_word (Or anything third in the list.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on some input by the community members I made the following change to make the logic of the regex pattern clearer.

```
/^(?:(?:.(?<!,))+,){2}\s*(\w+).*/x
```

**Explanation**

```
 /^ # 1.- Match start of line.
 (?:(?:.(?<!,))+ # 2.- Match but don't capture a secuence of character not containing a comma ...
 ,)              # 3.- followed by a comma  
 {2}             # 4.- (exactly two times) 
 \s*             # 5.- Match any optional space
 (\w+)           # 6.- Match and capture a secuence of the characters represented by \w a leat one character long. 
  .*             # 7.- Match anything after that if neccesary.
  /x
```

This is the one suggested previously.

```
/(?:\w+,?\s*){3}(\w+)/
```

Comment: I don't understand why you do the comma optional. It works for the example provided but makes the regex very fragile. It would fail with strings like `word1, word2, some_other_word, word_4` or `text word1, text word2, some_other_word, word_4`

Comment: It will watch `word_4` in given example, but `some_other_word` is required.

Comment: @M42: It works, but not the way he expects, I think. First ocurrence matches `text `, second one matches `word1, ` and third one matches `word2, ` (note spaces after each word).

Answer (score 1):

Try group 1 of this regex:

```
^(?:.*?,){2}\s*(.*?)\s*(,|$)
```

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/o2Qbp6cK8H) using your sample, plus an edge case, input showing capture in group 1.

Comment: This would match also leading and trailing spaces. I think the OP wants to skip them too.

Comment: @Birei OK. Added some whitespace munchers

Answer (score 0):

**It can't** only return one match at a time because your string has more than one *occurrence* of the same pattern and `Regular Expression` doesn't have a selective return option! ***So*** you can do whatever you want from the returned array.

```
,\s?([^,]+)
```

[See it in action](http://regex101.com/r/eV1uT4), 2nd matched group is what you need.